# How to get the title of the tag (not the commit) in git?

Tags: git, github

I created a new release on github, with the title "First release" and version "1.0.0"

I try to get the title of this release in command line like this:

```
git tag -n99 1.0.0
```

Unfortunately I get the message of the commit, instead of "First release"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `tag` is a **git concept** and can have only the `message` that is either supplied or prompted while creating.

A `Release`([doc](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases)) is a **GitHub concept** and is based on a git `tag`. The `Release` that is created on GitHub can be supplied with the `Release title` and that **title** is for the `Release` and not specifically the `tag`. Hence the `tag` doesn't have any information of the **title** supplied to the `Release`.

You are trying to get a `Release` metadata, **title** to be specific, using `git tag`, **which is not possible**.

You can try out GitHub's [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) to get `Release` related data.

Comment: How is it possible to access the tag message then? I can only see the commit message

Comment: @IterAtor That is because you might not have added a tag message while creating the tag. If you create a tag with `git tag 123 -m "Custom message"` and then run `git tag -n10 123`, that would show the message "Custom message". If no message was provided while creating the tag, then `git tag -n10 123` would only show the commit message

Answer (score 1):

GitHub release creates a lightweight tag. It does not contain a message at all, the title you enter is only readable via GitHub API.

You could create an annotated tag first (`git tag -a ...`), push it to GitHub and then proceed to create the release from that tag.